# get_posts() and WP_query limits 'AND' conditions to a maximum of 6 for meta value queries in Wordpress

Tags: php, wp-query, mysql, get-posts

The `get_posts()` function and `WP_query` in WordPress is limiting me to a maximum of 6 `AND` conditions for meta value queries. Can I force `get_posts()` to work with more than 6 `AND` conditions?

Below is an example of my query that is returning an empty array.

Code 1 below is the `print_r()` of the array that I am passing to get_posts() resulting in an empty array returned by `get_posts()`. Note I have tried multiple combinations of `AND` queries - this is just one example.

Code 2 below is identical to code 1, but I removed one `AND` statement and it returns a result.

For avoidance of doubt I have also included an example of a post detail in my database (as Code 3 below) that should match the query in code 1.

Code 4: shows the sql returned by `WP_query` when I pass the array directly to it. It also returns an empty array if I use more than 7 `AND` conditions

Code 1:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => page
    [posts_per_page] => 10000
    [category_name] => active-cards
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_purchase_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 46
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_balance_transfer_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 14
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_rewards_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_air_points_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_frequent_flyer_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_brand
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => amex
                            [1] => mastercard
                            [2] => visa
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_provider
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => anz
                            [1] => asb
                            [2] => bnz
                            [3] => westpac
                            [4] => kiwibank
                            [5] => tsb
                            [6] => warehouse_money
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

        )

)
```

Code 2:

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => page
    [posts_per_page] => 10000
    [category_name] => active-cards
    [meta_query] => Array
        (
            [relation] => AND
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_purchase_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 46
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_balance_transfer_rate
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 0
                            [1] => 14
                        )

                    [compare] => BETWEEN
                    [type] => NUMERIC
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [relation] => AND
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_rewards_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_air_points_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [key] => is_frequent_flyer_card
                            [value] => yes
                            [compare] => LIKE
                        )

                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [key] => card_brand
                    [value] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => amex
                            [1] => mastercard
                            [2] => visa
                        )

                    [compare] => IN
                    [type] => CHAR
                )

        )

)
```

Code 3 (this is an example of the post returned by code 2. Code 1 should also match this item but it returns nothing.

```
Array
(
    [0] => WP_Post Object
        (
            [ID] => 3742
            [post_author] => 1
            [post_date] => 2017-01-17 20:01:36
            [post_date_gmt] => 2017-01-17 09:01:36
            [post_title] => Westpac Airpoints Business MasterCard Credit Card
            [post_excerpt] => 
            [post_status] => publish
            [comment_status] => closed
            [ping_status] => closed
            [post_password] => 
            [post_name] => westpac-airpoints-business-mastercard-credit-card
            [to_ping] => 
            [pinged] => 
            [post_modified] => 2017-04-11 22:08:20
            [post_modified_gmt] => 2017-04-11 11:08:20
            [post_content_filtered] => 
            [post_parent] => 0
            [guid] => http://www.creditcardscompare.co.nz/?page_id=3742
            [menu_order] => 0
            [post_type] => page
            [post_mime_type] => 
            [comment_count] => 0
            [filter] => raw
            [meta] => Array
                (

                    [card_annual_fee] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 145
                        )

                    [card_purchase_rate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 20.95
                        )


                    [card_balance_transfer_rate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 1.99
                        )


                    [card_cash_rate] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 22.95
                        )


                    [card_interest_free_days] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 44
                        )

                    [card_provider] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Westpac
                        )

                    [card_brand] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Mastercard
                        )


                    [is_rewards_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )

                    [is_low_interest_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_no_annual_fee_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_balance_transfer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_student_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_prestige_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_air_new_zealand_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_air_points_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )

                    [is_frequent_flyer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )

                    [is_airpoint_lounge_access_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_best_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_black_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_business_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => a:1:{i:0;s:3:"yes";}
                        )


                    [is_cash_advance_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_cash_back_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_cheap_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_debit_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_flybuys_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_gold_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_high_income_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_home_loan_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_instant_approval_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_long_term_balance_transfer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_low_annual_fee_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_low_income_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_no_foreign_transaction_fee_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_platinum_card?] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_purchase_protection_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_qantas_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_signup_bonus_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_travel_insurance_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [is_zero_balance_transfer_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )


                    [is_zero_interest_card] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                        )

                    [card_star_rating] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 4
                        )

                )

            [post_url] => http://www.creditcardscompare.co.nz/westpac-airpoints-business-mastercard-credit-card/
        )
```

Lastly below is the actual SQL produced by wordpress when I run this using WP_Query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt2 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt2.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt3 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt3.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt4 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt4.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt5 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt5.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt6 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt6.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (78)
) AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'card_purchase_rate' AND CAST(wp_postmeta.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '30' ) 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = 'card_balance_transfer_rate' AND CAST(mt1.meta_value AS SIGNED) BETWEEN '0' AND '13' ) 
  AND 
  ( 
    ( mt2.meta_key = 'is_rewards_card' AND mt2.meta_value LIKE '%yes%' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt3.meta_key = 'is_air_points_card' AND mt3.meta_value LIKE '%yes%' ) 
    AND 
    ( mt4.meta_key = 'is_frequent_flyer_card' AND mt4.meta_value LIKE '%yes%' )
  ) 
  AND 
  ( mt5.meta_key = 'card_brand' AND mt5.meta_value IN ('amex','mastercard','visa') ) 
  AND 
  ( mt6.meta_key = 'card_provider' AND mt6.meta_value IN ('anz','asb','bnz','westpac','kiwibank','tsb','warehouse_money') )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'page' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10000
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to WPSE. Is it possible to summary your question? Currently it's too long, which possibly makes some visitors to just navigate away.

Comment: Hi Jack. I have edited it so that the first paragraph communicates the main question and made it easier to take in. The rest of the question is largely made of code the user can choose to ignore but would be valuable for most people to validate my question. I hope that helps.